# in c why the dereference of the s point to string value not working?

Tags: c

why when i use the program it return s = null

the `get_string` function  can have update to make the program work
it is : `string s = malloc(sizeof(string));`

but in the end of the function and after  `return s;` i cant `free(s);`
or before `return s;` i will lose the data i stored
i tried to search more about dereference pointers but i got nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* string;

string get_string(string q)
{

    string s = NULL;
    printf("%s",q);

    scanf("%s",s);

    return s;
}


int main(void)
{
    string a = get_string("name : ");

    printf("name is %s\n",a);

}
```

Comment: The function that called `get_string` would call `free`.

Comment: You can't think of `char *` as "strings", in the sense that high-level languages assign to this word. `scanf` expects a pre-allocated array of characters, not a null pointer.

Comment: `scanf("%s",s);` is undefined behavior. You can't read anything into a NULL pointer

Comment: Also, `sizeof(string)` is most likely 4 or 8, i.e. the size of a pointer.

Comment: I would strongly recommend avoiding to use a `typedef` for this. It literally does nothing for you but hide important information.

Comment: I suppose `string` is `typesef char* string;`. Don't do this, it only creates confusion, hence your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two correct uses of `scanf` to read a string:

```
char s1[10];
scanf("%9s", s1);

char *s2 = malloc(100);
scanf("%99s", s2);
```

Notice that in both cases — `s1` and `s2` — I had to explicitly say how much memory I wanted for my string.  Then, when I called `scanf`, I included that information — 1 less than the overall string size — in the `%s` format, so that I could tell `scanf` not to read a bigger string than my string variable could hold.

Notice, by contrast, that in your `get_string` function, you did not allocate any memory to hold your string at all.  Your variable `s` was a null pointer, explicitly pointing to no memory at all.

This is something that's very easy to overlook at first: *Most of the time, C does **not** allocate memory for strings for you.  Most of the time, this is **your** responsibility.*

Now, an additional concern is that even when you do allocate memory for a string, you have to think about how long that memory will stick around, and whether anyone has to explicitly deallocate it.  And there are some additional mistakes that are easy to make.  In particular, suppose you took my first example (`s1`) to heart, and tried to fix your `get_string` function like this:

```
char *get_string(char *q)
{
    char s[100];         /* WRONG */
    printf("%s",q);
    scanf("%99s",s);
    return s;
}
```

Here you have given `scanf` a proper array to read in to, *but* it's local to the `get_string` function, meaning that it will disappear after `get_string` returns, and it will be useless to the caller.

Another possibility is

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_string(char *q)
{
    char s = malloc(100);         /* better */
    if(s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s",q);
    scanf("%99s",s);
    return s;
}
```

This will work just fine.  Note that I have checked to see whether `malloc` succeeded.  (If it fails, it returns a `NULL` pointer.)  But now we have the issue that some memory has been allocated which might never be freed.  That is, `get_string` returns a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory, and it's the caller's responsibility to free that memory when it's no longer needed.  The caller doesn't *have* to, but if there end up being 1,000,000 calls to `get_string`, and if none of the allocated blocks ever gets freed, that's a lot of memory wasted.

Comment: thank you , but that mean when i use `char s = malloc(100);` in the `get_string`  function i can not free it  can make heap overflow and crash my pc

Comment: @MEDOS63 No, you will not crash your PC.  At worst you will eventually get that message `out of memory!` that it prints.  But these are not the only two ways of writing `get_string` -- there are other ways that don't have either problem.

Comment: @MEDOS63: You can free it just fine, it's just the caller's responsibility. Document that the result of `get_string` must be eventually released with `free`.

Answer (score 0):

First as other people have noted in the comments the Typedef in this case isn't very helpful as it hides the fact its a pointer. Also `char*` is vary commonly used and not a type complicated enough for a typedef IMO.

For your other issues the problem appears to be that you are thinking of the value as a C++ string instead of a char pointer. In C there aren't string objects but instead people use `char*` which can pointer blocks of chars and we determine the end of the string by putting a null character at the end of list of characters.

So the reason you can't print the NULL string is because it is undefined behavior to pass a NULL pointer to `printf`. When you change it to `s = malloc(sizeof(string));` the pointer is no longer null but instead pointing to the start of a block of memory that is `sizeof(string)` bytes long. You should be doing `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(q));` instead so you have a block of memory holding a string with the length of string q instead of just one character. More generally it would be `malloc(sizeof(char)*NUM_CHARS);`.

When it come to the free call. You can't call `free(s)` after `return s;` because no statements after `return s;` will occur because the function has returned and no longer executing. As for calling before, calling `free(s)` deallocates that block of memory that `s` is pointing too from the `malloc(sizeof(string))` is pointing to. Here you have to remember that the function isn't returning the memory or the string but instead **it returns the pointer to the string**. So if you delete the memory the pointer is pointing to then you lose it once you return.

Comment: And, by definition in C, `sizeof char === 1`, so one could simplify it further.

Comment: @Neil Except that there is no 'sizeof char' in C - you need to use parentheses on the type: `sizeof ( char )`. And there is no `===` operator in C, either.